# Core Data and UI Binding

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-data

My application builds its user interface and a core data model through code (no .xib .nib or .xcdatamodel files).

I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to bind core data entity attributes (in an NSManagedObject) with the object properties of a UIView or UIViewControler such that the two are kept synchronized with each other.

I could simply write code to move data between Core Data and the UI, then trap all events for field changes, but there are hints everywhere that this can be handled automatically using Key-Value mapping somehow.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me some sample code on how this binding is achieved through code?

Much appreciated.
Chris.

Answer (score 3):

Bindings are not available on iOS. Instead there is the [NSFetchedResultController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I'll investigate that.
Cheers.